# SSO authentication for Shiny Server

Tags: linux, webserver, authentication, ldap, single-sign-on

We have been using Shiny Server Pro with LDAP authentication. Now, we want to use Single Sign On (SSO) based service with Shiny Server Pro or the open source version (if possible).
I have looked in the official guide https://docs.posit.co/shiny-server but it doesn't seem to document what I'm trying to do.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated !

Comment: the documentation does not indicate any support for web-based SSO other than the google authentication federation scheme. look for a product that supports the authentication schemes your chosen sso uses (probably SAML or OIDC).